# Can the actor model replace a database?

Tags: actor-model, akka

After doing some research regarding the actor model, Im still not really sure what an actor actually is.. and what its supposed to "replace".
From what I have understood an actor is supposed to be an entity of some sort.. (a thing), and we use the actor model to change state of entities by sending and consuming messages.
So are actors supposed to "replace" entities stored in a database? And if "yes"..
A database would most likley be able to store millions of records of entities, but how would an actor model handle this, or am I getting it all wrong?

I do however understand the whole concept of an actor beeing async, and that we cant/shouldnt control on which machine/thread the actor is currently running on.
I also get that actors prevents us from having concurrent writes to an actor/entity..
So my main question as stated above, is that are actors supposed to "replace" storing entities in a database?

Comment: "Model" here just means "a conceptual way of thinking about things", it's not about databases. An actor model is a way of thinking about the building blocks of software and computation. E.g. like functional programming, procedural programming, object oriented programming - these are all different models. It has nothing to do with databases, at least not in the everyday sense. A programming language, or a library (or a database, for that matter) that would be built based on the actor model, would have features (keywords, facilities and constructs) that represent actor model concepts.

Answer (score 2):

An actor model is a way of thinking about concurrency, so it "replaces" other ways of thinking about concurrency, like async/await, or promises, or threads and locks, etc.

So think of where you might use a mutex, and you can use an actor there instead. Take the dining philosophers problem, for example. It can be implemented using philosopher actors that send a "pick up" message to chopstick actors. The chopstick actors send a "picked up" message back to the philosopher actor if it worked, or a "couldn't pick up" message otherwise.

It's a model for computation, not for storage, so when the chopstick actor receives a "pick up" message, it could store the "picked up state" in a boolean variable, or in a file, or a database table, or whatever.

Now in a *typical* implementation, state is usually stored in RAM, and you wouldn't have as many actors as a typical number of database rows. Technically you could make an in-memory key-value store with one actor per key, but you wouldn't want to. Often though, actors get created just for the course of a single transaction then destroyed afterward.

Answer (score 0):

> we use the actor model to change state of entities

In the actor model, all there are is actors (their addresses) and messages.  So, an actor can change the state of another actor by sending a message (but only if that other actor accepts the message and chooses to change its state).

> So are actors supposed to "replace" entities stored in a database?

They could do that, or they could replace the entire database.  There's no specification for how much or how little an actor can be or represent.  System designers can make choices.

> A database would most likley [sic] be able to store millions of records of entities, but how would an actor model handle this, or am I getting it all wrong?

There's no reason that an actor cannot use a database inside its implementation.

Comment: That all sounds nice in theory or speculation, but in practice, I doubt this frequently happens.  There really isn't any such thing as storing live objects (i.e. actors in a database), although I've seen scripts stored in a database that were stood up in processes as needed.  Postgres has an object model; I do wonder how often that gets actually used by software developers, or whether it could be considered an actor model in theory or practice.

Comment: So yes, a database can be an implementation detail for an actor or an actor model, but it's just one piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Erik Eidt, these are valid points, but I'm under the impression that, without some sort of an intro paragraph on what's meant by the "actor model", these might just go over the OP's head. From the phrasing of the question, it looks to me like the OP is confused by the fact that many people call database rows hydrated into objects ("entities" a la Entity Framework) - "models" (and put them in a project folder named "models"). It seems that the OP is thinking that an "actor model" is some kind of a data structure in a database, they are not thinking in terms of computational modeling.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, I think I get the basic concept of the actor model, and "most" of the parts its trying to solve. However, as mentioned in the question I have seen many samples where actors are used to store state of some sort of "entity", which makes me some what confused of how an actor can/should be used, since as also mentioned in the question, a database storing entities can store very many entities, since most relationa databases store their data on disk and some cache commonly accessed data in cache.. but from my understanding of actors, they are always stored in memory..

Comment: ..which makes me wonder.. if we for instance would say that we have very very many entities (lets say they are orders of some sort, orders as in someone has ordered a "set" or products). We have decided that all orders for our huge commerce application will be stored as actors, would that not end up in beeing extremly cost in-efficent since they would all be stored in memory (memory is more expensive, as in money, than disk space).. or am I getting this all wrong? The way I think of actors is basically "objects" thats living in memory, but not necessarily on the local machine, but could live..

Comment: on a remote machine.. infact we cant and shouldnt care where the actor lives, its up to the choosen "actor-framework" to decide where to "host" our new actors and also to distribute the messages between them.. we dont care where they "live".. Im also aware of other "benefits" (depends on the use case if some of it is to concider a benefit) that the actor models brings, such benefits like FIFO and the fact that an "actor" is "locked" for any state changes until a message is processed. But as I mentioned, the part I dont get is if we have very many actors running..

Comment: ..wouldnt that be extremly expensive? Or are actors that havent received any messages for a period of time put into some sort of "hibernation"-state and taken of memory until it receives a message? And just to clarify, now Im mainly focusing on if one would use the actor model to store state for "entities".

Comment: The actor model is abstract.  It does not mandate use of a particular memory technology.

Answer (score 0):

An actor is a state machine with an inbox. The inbox is an indirection of the access mode (direct from a calling thread, queue+worker, disruptor, etc.).
It may be a valid building block for a database, but for managing locking and transaction semantics, not for dealing with reading/writing.

Answer (score 0):

At a high-level conceptual view, the actor model and the concept of a database address orthogonal concerns.  The actor is concerned with how data/events are processed and the concept of a database is about how data can be stored, retrieved, and aggregated.

I think perhaps the heart of why you are asking this is due to the reality that, over time, relational databases have become the swiss army knives of software.  Much of what is done in databases has little or nothing to do with the concerns mentioned above.  In a lot of cases, I've seen (relational) databases used in ways that are inappropriate or at least sub-optimal.  An example relevant to your question (maybe even the reason for your question) is using database tables to implement a messaging solution.  Such approaches are common and can be made to work reasonably well with careful design.  They don't tend to scale or work terribly efficiently, though.  Queues/topics are more robust for this but they don't address persistent storage, retrieval, and aggregation as well as a database.  So instead of a database and a messaging platform, many people will just have a database.  I used to argue strongly against this but I've softened on this question.  It can be a pragmatic approach as long as you don't need a high-performance and/or scalable solution.  And if your team is not familiar with messaging (e.g. how reads modify the state of a queue) it might even be a good choice.

Coming at it from the other direction, you could build something more-or-less equivalent to an actor model using just a typical relational database that supports triggers and procedures.  This tends to not work well in practice, however, due to a number of factors.

The TLDR on this is that it's probably less that the actor model replaces the database but that the way you have seen databases used bleeds into concerns that are more squarely in the problem domain of the actor model.